Do environment variables override googleServicesFile for Firebase Auth?
I have inherited an Expo project and trying to figure out why the "Sign in with Google" feature is broken. I suspect there is a conflict of configuration for Firebase Auth.

On the one hand, app.json links to google-services.json which is the standard Firebase config file containing api_key and client_id.
On the other hand, the app code uses config.js to read the environment variables that were set in eas.json and the EAS Servers (see https://docs.expo.dev/eas/environment-variables/ and https://docs.expo.dev/eas/using-environment-variables/).

How can I work out which client id is "winning"?
Or how could I run an experiment to find out? The production builds are created on EAS servers so I don't think it's possible to debug them locally.

Excerpts from app.json:
{
  "expo": {
    "ios": {
      "googleServicesFile": "./GoogleService-Info.plist"
    },
    "android": {
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json"
    }
}

Excerpts from google-services.json:
{ 
  "client": { 
    "oauth_client": { 
       "client_id": "123456789-abcdef123456789.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    }
  }
}

Excerpts from config.js:
import { GOOGLE_ANDROID_CLIENT_ID } from "@env"; // using react-native-dotenv

const Config = {
  googleAndroidClientId: GOOGLE_ANDROID_CLIENT_ID
}

export default Config;

Environment variables are set in EAS Build:

GOOGLE_ANDROID_CLIENT_ID = 987654321-abcdef123456789.apps.googleusercontent.com


Update: I'm wondering if I need to convert app.json to app.config.js - but would this help? https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/variants/
